# aggregate columns by character

Tags: r, aggregate, taxonomy

Hi i would like to aggregate several columns.

```
d <- structure(list(Gene = structure(1:3, .Label = c("k141_20041_1", 
"k141_27047_2", "k141_70_3"), class = "factor"), phylum = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "Firmicutes", class = "factor"), class = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "Bacillales", class = "factor"), order = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "Bacilli", class = "factor"), family = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "Bacillaceae", class = "factor"), genus = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "Bacillus", class = "factor"), species = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("Bacillus subtilis", "unknown"), class = "factor"), 
    SampleA = c(0, 0, 0), SampleB = c(0, 0, 0), SampleCtrl = c(3.98888888888889, 
    11.5555555555556, 3.35978835978836)), .Names = c("Gene", 
"phylum", "class", "order", "family", "genus", "species", "SampleA", 
"SampleB", "SampleCtrl"), row.names = c(21918L, 40410L, 40857L
), class = "data.frame")
```

This in the input dataframe to aggregate

```
   Gene     phylum      class   order      family    genus           species SampleA SampleB
k141_20041_1 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus Bacillus subtilis       0       0
k141_27047_2 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus Bacillus subtilis       0       0
k141_70_3 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus           unknown       0       0
  SampleCtrl
  3.99
 11.56
  3.36
```

What i want at the end is one single line with all columns. In this case it would look like this (we can remove the gene column).

```
    phylum   class order  family  genus  species SampleA SampleB SampleCtrl
    Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus Bacillus subtilis       0       0     15.6
    Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus Bacillus Unknown       0       0     3.36
```

Note that is a very simple example. I have 20 samples and more than 500 species in the original dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
d%>%
group_by(phylum,class,order,family,genus, species)%>%
summarise_if(is.numeric, sum)    
Groups: phylum, class, order, family, genus [?]

      phylum      class   order      family    genus           species SampleA SampleB SampleCtrl
      <fctr>     <fctr>  <fctr>      <fctr>   <fctr>            <fctr>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus Bacillus subtilis       0       0   15.54444
2 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus           unknown       0       0    3.35979
```

Comment: I want to aggregate all sample columns (not just the samplectrl column). It was not clear from my question. This example will only aggreagate Samplectrl column. I have more than 20 column , do i have to list them all in such case ??

Comment: @david I edited my answer. SampleA and SampleB are now summed too as they are numeric also.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the sample columns are numeric and the others are not and that the aggregation desired is to sum each sample column grouping by the other columns (except Gene):

```
j <- which(sapply(d, is.numeric))
aggregate(d[j], d[-c(1, j)], sum)
```

giving:

```
      phylum      class   order      family    genus           species SampleA
1 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus Bacillus subtilis       0
2 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus           unknown       0
  SampleB SampleCtrl
1       0  15.544444
2       0   3.359788
```

Another possibility if the sample columns all have `Sample` in their names and the other columns do not is to use this instead of the first line above:

```
j <- grep("Sample", names(d))
```

or if neither of the above assumptions hold then if we know that the sample columns are the last 3 columns then:

```
j <- seq(to = ncol(d), length = 3)
```

**Update:** fixed and added two alternatives.

Comment: Thanks it also works !!! All sample columns are indeed numeric. They have different names but thanks for the answer